# Dynamically set database parameters

Tags: symfony

I want to dynamically set database configurations (username, host, password, etc...) placed in `app/config/parameters.yml` file.

What I mean by "dynamically" is based on some form input.

Is this possible? And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the form to write the parameters.yml file with new parameters or do you want to store container parameters in database ( possible security issue if others gain acces to your databse )

Comment: Storing them in yml file only is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [Sensio/SensioDistributionBundle](https://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle) which is already included in the symfony standard edition.

It does exactly what you're looking for. Setting basic parameters in parameters.yml file.

The class performing the actual writing of the parameters.yml is [Sensio\DistributionBundle\Configurator\Configurator](https://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Configurator/Configurator.php).

```
use Sensio\DistributionBundle\Configurator\Configurator;
```

Now use the configurator in your Controller.

```
   $configurator = new Configurator($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir());

   $configurator->mergeParameters(array(
        'my_parameter' = 'my_value',
        'my_parameter2' = 'my_value2',
   ));

  $configurator->write();
}
```

The best thing will be looking at the Configurator class itself to understand how it works.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: jeah combined with reading current data with YAML::parse checking for existence of the file and Yaml::dump - thats why i choose to hint you to the configurator ... less work implementing :)